# VBA error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

Tags: vba, excel

I wrote following code to copy the content from current worksheet to create a new workbook, if I don't double click the new created workbook, the code can be invoked without any errors, but once I open the new created workbook and close it, the code will throw exception :

```
Automation error :
The object invoked has disconnected from its clients
```

see my code below:

```
Private Sub saveReportContents(smInstance As String, companyCode As String, jobName As String, onb_grp As String)
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Activate
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Copy before:=wb.Sheets(1)

    fileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "TDL_CTI_Onboard_" & smInstance & "_" & companyCode & "_" & jobName & "_" & onb_grp & "_" & _
               Format(Now, "yyyymmdd_hhmmss") & ".xlsx"

    wb.SaveAs fileName
    For Each butt In wb.Sheets("Contacts").Buttons
        butt.Delete
    Next butt
    wb.Sheets("Contacts").Rows(1).EntireRow.Delete
    wb.Save
    wb.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

the error line that will be highlighted VBA code editor is:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Contacts").Copy before:=wb.Sheets(1)
```

I don't know why, could you guys tell me the reason and how to avoid this issue?

Comment: If saveReportContents() sub belongs to the sheet that gets copied Excel might get confused about the reference to **ThisWorkbook**. Try replacing `ThisWorkbook` with `ActiveWorkbook` or `Workbooks("ExplicitFileName")`, and also add `Set wb = Nothing` after closing it